# How to allow extensions to modify Chrome "protected" pages?

Tags: google-chrome

When I open a new page, since my default is set to DDG, I get the DuckDuckGo blindingly white search page. I would like to modify it so that the `Dark Reader` automatically modifies it, but I'm confronted with:

```
This page is protected by browser
```

How do you allow overrides in Chrome's settings for protected pages?

Answer (score 9):

Due to security reasons, Google Chrome forbids extensions from modifying protected pages. You can't change that via settings.

Protected pages are those whose URLs start with:
`chrome://`
`chrome-extension://`
`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/`

Extensions are also unable to modify the following types of pages:

- PDF documents
- Pages where Javascript is disabled
- Security warning pages
- Error pages (e.g 404 errors, network errors, etc.)
- URLs starting with `view-source:` or `data:`

Answer (score 2):

Open chrome://flags/ in a new tab, search for "dark", there should be open called "Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents" change the value to "Enable". Enjoy! Don't forget to like and accept the solution if it works for you ;)

Comment: Wow - this seems to have made the Dark Reader extension unnecessary and even works on the Chrome Store.  Elegant!

Comment: @odigity although the issue is that you cannot choose to disable it for *some* websites only, instead it is either globally turned on, or globally turned off...right?

Comment: @bzm3r that's correct. Unfortunately, this is a global flag that automatically applies to all websites (this is a downside of this approach).

Comment: Great approach, hope that implement in main features of chrome